# Convert NA to 0 in columns selected by name using dplyr mutate across

Tags: r, na, dplyr

This is an example of my data

```
df = data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 1), 
                test = sample(40:100, 3), 
                Sets = c(NA,4,4),
                CheWt = c(NA,4,NA),
                LatWt = c(NA,5,5))
```

I'd like to turn all the `NA` to  `0` in columns which have `"Wt"` in the header. I am trying to use dplyr and  `mutate` `across`

```
df = df%>%
  mutate(across(contains("Wt"), replace(is.na(), 0)))
```

This is the error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x argument "values" is missing, with no default
i Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
```

Comment: `replace()` takes 3 args and you were only passing it 2. `mutate(across(contains("Wt"), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)))`

Comment: `df[grep("Wt", names(df))][is.na(df[grep("Wt", names(df))])] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` needs 3 arguments: the value, the index of values to replace, and the replacement. And you need to use `~` for purrr-style anonymous functions:

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Wt"), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
df
#   id test Sets CheWt LatWt
# 1  1   93   NA     0     0
# 2  2   44    4     4     5
# 3  3   80    4     0     5
```

Or you can use `replace_na` for a somewhat simpler interface:

```
df = df%>%
  mutate(across(contains("Wt"), replace_na, 0))
df
#   id test Sets CheWt LatWt
# 1  1   73   NA     0     0
# 2  2   43    4     4     5
# 3  3   54    4     0     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `ifelse` and `is.na`.

```r
library(dplyr)


df = data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 1), 
                test = sample(40:100, 3), 
                Sets = c(NA,4,4),
                CheWt = c(NA,4,NA),
                LatWt = c(NA,5,5))


df = mutate(df, across(contains("Wt"), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))


#>   id test Sets CheWt LatWt
#> 1  1   97   NA     0     0
#> 2  2   79    4     4     5
#> 3  3   75    4     0     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>